# Button styling with touch feedback

Tags: android, android-styles

How do I give a custom style that would enable me to put in `corners` and a `drawable` in the same in a button. The current way I am implementing this gives me an error:

Main Implemented background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/comment"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_selected="false"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/comment_pressed"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

comment.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/purple"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

comment_pressed:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Here the `@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light` is a drawable from the `Sherlock` library. And I do know that the error is from here. Is there anyway that I could achieve this ?? Curved edges plus a drawable item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the resources used in the `Sherlock` library you will see that abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light contains the following:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_pressed_holo_light"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_longpressed_holo"  />
</transition>
```

Which refers to the following 9Patch images:
[image: abs__list_pressed_holo_light] abs__list_pressed_holo_light
[image] abs__list_longpressed_holo

The `<corners android:radius="x"/>` attribute is used for `<shape>` items, and has no meaning for 9Patch drawables.

To get around this, you could either;

- create your own 9Patch drawables with radiused corners in a graphic editor, and use these instead of the default ones in the Sherlock library.

or

- replace the 9Patch items in the `<transition>` with your own "rectangle" `<shape>` items. Set the color of these `<shape>` items to mimic the colors used in the 9Patches. You would then be able to use the `<corners>` attribute with these '' items.

**Edit:** 
You need to understand that the `abs__list_pressed_holo_light` and `abs__list_longpressed_holo` files in the Sherlock library are not solid color hex values. They are nine-patch png bitmaps. Where you wrote;

```
<solid android:color="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light"/>
```

...in your xml, you were actually pointing at two bitmaps instead of at a color value.

Of the two possible solutions I suggested previously, I think the second option is probably best in your case. Here is a step by step of how you would do it.

1) Create two `<shape>` drawables and save them in your `drawable` folder:

**`my_holo_light_blue_shape`**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#9933B5E5"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**`my_holo_dark_blue_shape`**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#CC0099CC"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

2) Create your own `<transition>` drawable and once again save it in your `drawable` folder:

**`my_holo_blue_transition`**

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_holo_light_blue_shape"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_holo_dark_blue_shape"  />
</transition>
```

3) You can then use your new `<transition>` drawable for the pressed state in your selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/comment"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_selected="false"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_holo_blue_transition"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: thank you there, I actually did see those drawable things, but I wish to have used the curve along with the drawable.

Comment: There are several different types of drawable. The drawables used in `abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_light` are `<nine-patch>` drawables. The type you can use `<corners>` with are `<shape>` drawables. [Have a look at this link to get a better understanding of drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). You cannot use the `<corners>` attribute with `<nine-patch>` drawables. The `<nine-patch>` does not know what to do with that attribute. It's not how they work. If you want to use `<corners>` you will have to use `<shape>` drawables.